# Generate number on click then pass that to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Say I have some text and a button:

```
<p id="text-box">placeholder text</p>
<button id="text-btn">New Quote Please.</button>
```

When I click the button I want something new to appear in the #text-box. So I create an array and some jQuery functions:

```
var textArr = [word0, word1, word2, word3, word4...];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#text-btn" ).click(function(){
    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*textArr.length); //This line is the problem.
  });
  $("#text-box").html(textArr[x]);
});
```

The idea is when the button is clicked a random number is generated then that number is used to select an item in textArr to display in #text-box. I am fairly certain that the problem lays in the commented line. I think that the x value in the $("#text-btn") function is either not being created at all or is not being passed into the $("#text-box") function.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `quoteArr` does not appear defined . Try substituting `textArr` for `quoteArr` at `x = Math.floor(Math.random()*quoteArr.length); //This line is the problem.`

Comment: Shouldn't `quoteArr.length` be `textArr.length`? Also, your `x` variable is local to your anonymous function, so it seems to be undefined by the time you try to use it in `textArr[x]`. Does this help? If so, let me know and I'll post as an answer.

Comment: sorry, brainfart. I renamed everything to simplify my problem and forgot one. It is supposed to be textArr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some minor mistakes

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textArr = ['word0', 'word1', 'word2', 'word3',' word4'];
  $( "#text-btn" ).click(function(){
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(textArr.length));
       $("#text-box").text(textArr[x]);
  });

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ts5fesf9/)

**Update**

Some mistakes I found is:

1. you put the `$("#text-box").text(textArr[x]);` out side the click function
2. missing bracket  `x = Math.floor(Math.random()*textArr.length);`, correct  format is  `var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(textArr.length));`
3. Array elements should have quotes (since it is strings).
4. define array inside `document.ready` function.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate on my mistakes?

Answer (score 2):

Show us console try console.log . and text-box html must be inside click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#text-btn" ).click(function(){
    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*quoteArr.length); //This line is the problem.
     console.log('check', Math.floor(Math.random()*quoteArr.length)) 
   $("#text-box").html(textArr[x]);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, what's quoteArr? you're referencing the wrong array name! try this.

```
x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(textArr.length));
```

Comment: sorry, brainfart. I renamed everything to simplify my problem and forgot one. It is supposed to be textArr.